# Need help on Javascript operators comparison in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, operator-keyword

I'm coding a game and I want to implement a script that make a different game over text according to the score all this in the html. But it doesn't work and display the old header.

What did I do wrong ? Here's my code :

```
 <div id="game-over">
      <h3><font color="orange">Tu as courus <span id="score"></span> mètres.</font></h3>
      <font color="orange"><h1 id="customegotext">oldHeader</h1></font>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button restart">Ressayer ?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  function myFunction() { 
    var scoretext;
    if ("score" < 44) {
        scoretext = "La prochaine fois essaye de dépasser le premier saut";
    } else {
        scoretext = "Caca";
    }
    var element = document.getElementById("oldHeader");
    element.innerHTML = "scoretext";
}
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ljdm.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont see where you call the function neither any id called oldHeader

Comment: `"score" < 44` compares the string `score` to `44`. The result is always `false`, because `s` comes after `4` in the Unicode table.

Comment: And `element.innerHTML = "scoretext";` should be `element.innerHTML = scoretext;`

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: You have no element with the id `oldHeader`, but you do have an element that contains a text node "oldHeader" but with an id of `customegotext`

Comment: So how do I do Xufox

Answer (score 1):

You Should refer to "customegotext" to change the content of the OLDHeader document.getElementById("customegotext").innerHTML = "newheader"

Comment: Thanks but now it show "scoretext" instead of the actual text